# How to use foreach sink in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

How can I use `foreach` in Python Spark structured streaming to trigger ops on output.

```py
query = wordCounts\
    .writeStream\
    .outputMode('update')\
    .foreach(func)\
    .start()

def func():
    ops(wordCounts)
```

Comment: I'm sure there was a question about this already that would make it a duplicate but can't find it

Answer (score 8):

Support for the foreach sink in Python has been added in Spark 2.4.0 and the documentation has been updated: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch

Make sure that you have that version and you can now do:

```py
def process_row(row):
    # Process row
    pass

query = streamingDF.writeStream.foreach(process_row).start()
```

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR** It is not possible to use `foreach` method in pyspark.

Quoting the [official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach) of Spark Structured Streaming (highlighting mine):

> The foreach operation allows arbitrary operations to be computed on the output data. As of Spark 2.1, **this is available only for Scala and Java**.

Comment: thanks a lot, i wonder is there a tricked way to using foreach in structured streaming?  And is it possible to use cache or persist in structured streaming?

Comment: Mind elaborating on _"is there a tricked way to using foreach in structured streaming?"_? No caching or persist as the DataFrame per trigger is a "very temporary" data structure and the purpose of Spark "Streams" is that you should not be concerned with the low-level execution details whatsoever.

Comment: "foreachBatch(...) [...]. Since Spark 2.4, this is supported in Scala, Java and *Python*". So, Python is supported as of Spark 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to use `foreach` in `pyspark` using any simple tricks now, besides, in `pyspark`, the `update` output mode is only ready for debugging.

I'd recommand you to use spark in `scala`, it's not hard to learn.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [DataFrame.foreach(f)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreach) instead.