# Structured spark streaming - foreach

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I use pyspark 2.3.
I need to read a stream of data, and in the end write it to oracle. 
I want to use the new streaming api, the structured streaming api.
As far as I know, there is no built-in jdbc writer that I can use, with Stream DataFrame.

I tried to run the foreach method, and than write micro-batches, but it seems that the foreach method is not available in pyspark 2.3.

Does there is any way of using the structured streaming api with pyspark 2.3, and than to write the DataFrame to oracle?

Comment: Try upgrading your Spark to 2.4  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54269802/2308683